# Android 4.2: back stack behaviour with nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

With Android 4.2, the support library got support for nested fragments [see here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). I've played around with it and found an interesting behaviour / bug regarding back stack and [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29). When using getChildFragmentManager() and addToBackStack(String name), by pressing the back button the system does not run down the back stack to the previous fragment. 
On the other hand, when using [getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) and addToBackStack(String name), by pressing the back button the system returns to the previous fragment.

For me, this behaviour is unexpected. By pressing the back button on my device, I'm expecting that the last added fragment to the back stack will be popped, even if the fragment was added to the back stack in the children's fragment manager.

Is this behaviour correct? Is this behaviour a bug? Is there a work around for this issue?

## sample code with getChildFragmentManager():

```
public class FragmentceptionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    final FrameLayout wrapper1 = new FrameLayout(this);
    wrapper1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    wrapper1.setId(1);

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.topMargin = 0;

    final TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(params);
    text.setText("fragment 1");
    wrapper1.addView(text);

    setContentView(wrapper1);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
            .add(1, new Fragment1()).commit();
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper2 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper2.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper2.setId(2);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 100;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 2");
        wrapper2.addView(text);

        return wrapper2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(2, new Fragment2()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper3 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper3.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper3.setId(3);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 200;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 3");
        wrapper3.addView(text);

        return wrapper3;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(3, new Fragment3()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper4 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper4.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper4.setId(4);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 300;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 4");
        wrapper4.addView(text);

        return wrapper4;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(4, new Fragment4()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper5 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper5.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper5.setId(5);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 400;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 5");
        wrapper5.addView(text);

        return wrapper5;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}

}
```

## sample code with getFragmentManager():

```
public class FragmentceptionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    final FrameLayout wrapper1 = new FrameLayout(this);
    wrapper1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    wrapper1.setId(1);

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.topMargin = 0;

    final TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(params);
    text.setText("fragment 1");
    wrapper1.addView(text);

    setContentView(wrapper1);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
            .add(1, new Fragment1()).commit();
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper2 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper2.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper2.setId(2);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 100;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 2");
        wrapper2.addView(text);

        return wrapper2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(2, new Fragment2()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper3 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper3.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper3.setId(3);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 200;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 3");
        wrapper3.addView(text);

        return wrapper3;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(3, new Fragment3()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper4 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper4.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper4.setId(4);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 300;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 4");
        wrapper4.addView(text);

        return wrapper4;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(4, new Fragment4()).commit();
    }
}

public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout wrapper5 = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        wrapper5.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wrapper5.setId(5);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = 400;

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setText("fragment 5");
        wrapper5.addView(text);

        return wrapper5;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: hmmm thats very interesting. I don't I'd expect that behavior either. If this is the case then it seems that we might have override on OnBackPressed and in that method get a hold of the fragment with child fragments then get a hold of the ChildFragmentManager to execute a pop transaction.

Comment: @Marco, Exactly, but however it's a workaround. Why won't the API work properly?

Answer (score 71):

This solution may be better version of @Sean answer:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // if there is a fragment and the back stack of this fragment is not empty,
    // then emulate 'onBackPressed' behaviour, because in default, it is not working
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
        if (frag.isVisible()) {
            FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
            if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                childFm.popBackStack();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Again, I prepared this solution based on @Sean answer above.

As @AZ13 said, this solution is only feasible in one level child fragments situations. In multiple level fragments case, works become a little complex, so I recommend that try this solution only the feasible case I have said. =)

**Note:** Since `getFragments` method is now a private method, this solution will not work. You can check comments for a link which suggests a solution about this situation.

Comment: 林奕忠 answer should be used instead of this one - it correctly handles multiple nested fragments

Comment: Is it really working code? Even getFragments is not public method? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42572412/4729203

Comment: It worked  once but may not be working now if getFragments is not public anymore.

Comment: `getFragments` is now public.

Comment: this does not work correctly if you have FragA -> Frag B -> Frag C inside Pager...

Comment: > As @AZ13 said, this solution is only feasible in one level child fragments situations. In multiple level fragments case, works become a little complex, so I recommend that try this solution only the feasible case I have said. =)

Answer (score 58):

Seems like a bug.
Take a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40323

For a workaround I've used successfully (as suggested in comments):

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // If the fragment exists and has some back-stack entry
    if (mActivityDirectFragment != null && mActivityDirectFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        // Get the fragment fragment manager - and pop the backstack
        mActivityDirectFragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    // Else, nothing in the direct fragment back stack
    else{
        // Let super handle the back press
        super.onBackPressed();          
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this not a proper solution and just a workaround for the simplest case. Just assume you have a fragment, which contains another fragment, which containes another fragment and so on. Then you have to  propagate the call down to the last fragment which contains another one or more fragment :/

Comment: @MuhammadBabar No, you won't. If it's a null, the second part of the statement won't be evaluated because it's already determined false. the operand is & and not | .

Answer (score 29):

The real answer to this question is in the Fragment Transaction's function called setPrimaryNavigationFragment.

```
/**
 * Set a currently active fragment in this FragmentManager as the primary navigation fragment.
 *
 * <p>The primary navigation fragment's
 * {@link Fragment#getChildFragmentManager() child FragmentManager} will be called first
 * to process delegated navigation actions such as {@link FragmentManager#popBackStack()}
 * if no ID or transaction name is provided to pop to. Navigation operations outside of the
 * fragment system may choose to delegate those actions to the primary navigation fragment
 * as returned by {@link FragmentManager#getPrimaryNavigationFragment()}.</p>
 *
 * <p>The fragment provided must currently be added to the FragmentManager to be set as
 * a primary navigation fragment, or previously added as part of this transaction.</p>
 *
 * @param fragment the fragment to set as the primary navigation fragment
 * @return the same FragmentTransaction instance
 */
public abstract FragmentTransaction setPrimaryNavigationFragment(Fragment fragment);
```

You have to set this function on the initial parent fragment when the activity is adding it. I have a replaceFragment function inside of my activity that looks like this:

```
public void replaceFragment(int containerId, BaseFragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
    if (addToBackstack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.TAG);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment).commit();
}
```

This gives you the same behavior as if your clicking back from regular Fragment B back to Fragment A, except now it is on the child fragments as well!

Comment: Great find! This resolves the issue mentioned by the OP in a much cleaner and less hackie way.

Comment: Thats crashing unless part of the navigation library as a HavHostFragment

Answer (score 24):

This solution may be better version of @ismailarilik answer:

Nested Fragment version

```
private boolean onBackPressed(FragmentManager fm) {
    if (fm != null) {
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
            return true;
        }

        List<Fragment> fragList = fm.getFragments();
        if (fragList != null && fragList.size() > 0) {
            for (Fragment frag : fragList) {
                if (frag == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (frag.isVisible()) {
                    if (onBackPressed(frag.getChildFragmentManager())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (onBackPressed(fm)) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't appear to work when there are multiple levels of nested fragments

Comment: Cloud you give me your architecture of nested fragments? In my app it works. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: The order for popping the backstack is not as I expected in this example. I believe you should first find the most deeply nested visible fragment in the tree and attempt to pop the backstack on that, then progressively move up the tree looking for other visible fragments where you could pop the backstack until you get one. A quick fix that handles the simplest cases is to change the onBackPressed(FragmentManager fm) function and switch the block that pops the backstack with the one that enumerates fragments. That way popping the backstack in more deeply nested child fragments will happen first

Comment: Also, when you have a lot of nested fragments, each with their child fragments that may cover part of the screen, the idea of having a separate backstack for each child fragment manager stops making sense. The backstack should be unified across all fragments in the activity, and track fragment changes in the order in which they happen, regardless of the nesting level of the fragment.

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution without the `SupportFragmentManager` and instead just the Standard `FragmentManager`?

Comment: According source code, the answer is  YES.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.getFragmentManager%28%29

Comment: the standard FragmentManager from `android.app` doesn't have the `getFragments()` API

Comment: This is using android.support.v4.app lib

Comment: i have done a demo but see error here anybody pls hving error with childfragments  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052712/nested-fragment-backpress-child-inside-parent-have-problem

Answer (score 14):

With this answer it will handle recursive back checking and give each fragment the chance to override the default behaviour. This means you can have a fragment that hosts a ViewPager do something special like scroll to the page that as a back-stack, or scroll to the home page and then on the next back press exit.

Add this to your Activity that extends AppCompatActivity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(!BaseFragment.handleBackPressed(getSupportFragmentManager())){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Add this to your BaseFragment or the class you can have all your fragments inherit from.

```
public static boolean handleBackPressed(FragmentManager fm)
{
    if(fm.getFragments() != null){
        for(Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()){
            if(frag != null && frag.isVisible() && frag instanceof BaseFragment){
                if(((BaseFragment)frag).onBackPressed()){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

protected boolean onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    if(handleBackPressed(fm)){
        return true;
    }
    else if(getUserVisibleHint() && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fm.popBackStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is great answer, working on API level 23/24 and with support lib 24.1.1

Comment: Have been using this for some time now, it's a great solution - but recently having compile warnings about direct access to getFragments() from outside library group.  Have you already updated with a work-around?

Comment: is something fixed or in 2020 we still have the issue and should implement your solution??!!

Answer (score 6):

This code will navigate the tree of fragment managers and return the last one that was added that has any fragments it can pop off the stack:

```
private FragmentManager getLastFragmentManagerWithBack(FragmentManager fm)
{
  FragmentManager fmLast = fm;

  List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();

  for (Fragment f : fragments)
  {
    if ((f.getChildFragmentManager() != null) && (f.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0))
    {
      fmLast = f.getFragmentManager();
      FragmentManager fmChild = getLastFragmentManagerWithBack(f.getChildFragmentManager());

      if (fmChild != fmLast)
        fmLast = fmChild;
    }
  }

  return fmLast;
}
```

Call the method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  FragmentManager fm = getLastFragmentManagerWithBack(getSupportFragmentManager());

  if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
  {
    fm.popBackStack();
    return;
  }

  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: This works for all nested fragment if its registered correctly !! +100

Comment: it is worked! after testing other approach , it is worked for complex nested fragments. when you have a fragment inside a Main fragment and that main fragment is in MainActivity, this approach works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented it correctly if anybody didnt found any answer till now

just add this method on your child nested fragment

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true ) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event
            FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
            if (fm != null) {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                    Log.e( "Frag","back" );

                }

                List<Fragment> fragList = fm.getFragments();
                if (fragList != null && fragList.size() > 0) {
                    for (Fragment frag : fragList) {
                        if (frag == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (frag.isVisible()) {
                          Log.e( "Frag","Visible" );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this  line `requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback) `

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your Activity derives from FragmentActivity, which handles the BACK key press (see line 173 of [FragmentActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java).

In our application, I'm using a ViewPager (with fragments) and each fragment can have nested fragments. The way I've handled this is by:

- defining an interface OnBackKeyPressedListener with a single method `void onBackKeyPressed()`
- implemented this interface in "top" fragments that ViewPager shows
- overriding onKeyDown and detecting BACK press, and calling onBackKeyPressed in a currently active fragment in the view pager.

Also note, that I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()` in the fragments to properly nest fragments. You can see a discussion and an explanation in [this android-developers post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/XfoNNIkolmg).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using fragment in a fragment then use `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_name, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

if you are using child fragment and replace it use `getParentFragmentManager()`

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_name, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

if both are not working for you try this `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_name, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to handle fragment back stack by adding to the parent fragment this method at the onCreate View() method and passing the root view.

```
private void catchBackEvent(View v){
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
                if(isEnableFragmentBackStack()){
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                                    setEnableFragmentBackStack(false);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;   
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );
}
```

The method isEnableFragmentBackStack() is a boolean flag to know when i'm on the main fragment or the next one.

Make sure that when you commit the fragment that needs to be have stack, then you must add the addToBackstack Method.

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be better, bacause it checks all the levels of nested fragments:

```
 /**
 * This method will go check all the back stacks of the added fragments and their nested fragments
 * to the the {@code FragmentManager} passed as parameter.
 * If there is a fragment and the back stack of this fragment is not empty,
 * then emulate 'onBackPressed' behaviour, because in default, it is not working.
 *
 * @param fm the fragment manager to which we will try to dispatch the back pressed event.
 * @return {@code true} if the onBackPressed event was consumed by a child fragment, otherwise {@code false}.
 */
public static boolean dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(FragmentManager fm) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    boolean result;
    if (fragments != null && !fragments.isEmpty()) {
        for (Fragment frag : fragments) {
            if (frag != null && frag.isAdded() && frag.getChildFragmentManager() != null) {
                // go to the next level of child fragments.
                result = dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(frag.getChildFragmentManager());
                if (result) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the back stack is not empty then we pop the last transaction.
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

in your activity `onBackPressed` you can simply call it this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                // if there is a fragment and the back stack of this fragment is not empty,
                // then emulate 'onBackPressed' behaviour, because in default, it is not working
                if (!dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(fm)) {
                    // if no child fragment consumed the onBackPressed event,
                    // we execute the default behaviour.
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for their help, this (tweaked version) works for me:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!recursivePopBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager())) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

/**
 * Recursively look through nested fragments for a backstack entry to pop
 * @return: true if a pop was performed
 */
public static boolean recursivePopBackStack(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    if (fragmentManager.getFragments() != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments()) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                boolean popped = recursivePopBackStack(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
                if (popped) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

NOTE: You will probably also want to set the background color of these nested fragments to the app theme's window background color, as by default they are transparent. Somewhat outside of the scope of this question, but it is accomplished by resolving the attribute android.R.attr.windowBackground, and setting the Fragment view's background to that resource ID.

Answer (score 1):

More than 5 years and this issue is still relevant. If you do not want to use the fragmentManager.getFragments() due to its restriction. Extend and use the below classes:

**NestedFragmentActivity.java**

```
abstract public class NestedFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Stack<Integer> mActiveFragmentIdStack = new Stack<>();
    private final Stack<String> mActiveFragmentTagStack = new Stack<>();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mActiveFragmentIdStack.size() > 0 && mActiveFragmentTagStack.size() > 0) {

            // Find by id
            int lastFragmentId = mActiveFragmentIdStack.lastElement();
            NestedFragment nestedFragment = (NestedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(lastFragmentId);

            // If cannot find by id, find by tag
            if (nestedFragment == null) {
                String lastFragmentTag = mActiveFragmentTagStack.lastElement();
                nestedFragment = (NestedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);
            }

            if (nestedFragment != null) {
                nestedFragment.onBackPressed();
            }

            // If cannot find by tag, then simply pop
            mActiveFragmentTagStack.pop();
            mActiveFragmentIdStack.pop();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void addToBackStack(int fragmentId, String fragmentTag) {
        mActiveFragmentIdStack.add(fragmentId);
        mActiveFragmentTagStack.add(fragmentTag);
    }
}
```

**NestedFragment.java**

```
abstract public class NestedFragment extends Fragment {

    private final Stack<Integer> mActiveFragmentIdStack = new Stack<>();
    private final Stack<String> mActiveFragmentTagStack = new Stack<>();

    private NestedFragmentActivity mParentActivity;
    private NestedFragment mParentFragment;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (getParentFragment() == null) {
            try {
                mParentActivity = (NestedFragmentActivity) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement " + NestedFragmentActivity.class.getName());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                mParentFragment = (NestedFragment) getParentFragment();
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(getParentFragment().getClass().toString()
                        + " must implement " + NestedFragment.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (mActiveFragmentIdStack.size() > 0 && mActiveFragmentTagStack.size() > 0) {

            // Find by id
            int lastFragmentId = mActiveFragmentIdStack.lastElement();
            NestedFragment nestedFragment = (NestedFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(lastFragmentId);

            // If cannot find by id, find by tag
            if (nestedFragment == null) {
                String lastFragmentTag = mActiveFragmentTagStack.lastElement();
                nestedFragment = (NestedFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);
            }

            if (nestedFragment != null) {
                nestedFragment.onBackPressed();
            }

            // If cannot find by tag, then simply pop
            mActiveFragmentIdStack.pop();
            mActiveFragmentTagStack.pop();

        } else {
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }

    private void addToBackStack(int fragmentId, String fragmentTag) {
        mActiveFragmentIdStack.add(fragmentId);
        mActiveFragmentTagStack.add(fragmentTag);
    }

    public void addToParentBackStack() {
        if (mParentFragment != null) {
            mParentFragment.addToBackStack(getId(), getTag());
        } else if (mParentActivity != null) {
            mParentActivity.addToBackStack(getId(), getTag());
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Each activity and fragment extended from the above classes manages their own back stack for each of their children, and children's children, and so on. The backstack is simply a record of "active fragment" tags/ids. So the caveat is to always provide a tag and/or id for your fragment.

When adding to the backstack in a childFragmentManager, you will need to also call "addToParentBackStack()". This ensures that the fragment's tag/id is added in the parent fragment/activity for later pops.

Example:

```
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.fragment,
            fragment,
            fragment.getTag()
    ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    addToParentBackStack();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by keeping currently opened fragment in property of activity. Then I override method

> ```
>  // INSIDE ACTIVITY
>  override fun onBackPressed() {
>     val fragment = currentFragment
>
>     if(fragment != null && fragment.childFragmentManager.fragments.any()){
>         fragment.childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
>     }
>     else {
>         super.onBackPressed()
>     }
> }
> ```

This is how I add child fragment into currently opened fragment from within itself.

> ```
>  // INSIDE FRAGMENT
>  menu_fragment_view.setBackgroundColor(-((Math.random() * 10000 ).toInt() % 30000)) // to see change
>  add_fragment_button.setOnClickListener {
>         val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>
>         transaction.add(R.id.menu_fragment_fragment_holder, MenuFragment())
>
>         transaction.addToBackStack(null)
>
>         transaction.commit()
>     }
> ```

This is xml layout of parent fragment and added fragment

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>      android:layout_width="match_parent"
>      android:layout_height="match_parent"
>      android:id="@+id/menu_fragment_view">
>      <Button
>          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>          android:id="@+id/add_fragment_button"
>          android:text="Just add fragment"/>
>      <FrameLayout
>          android:id="@+id/menu_fragment_fragment_holder"
>          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>          android:layout_height="match_parent"
>          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/> 
> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After observing some solutions presented here, I found that to allow flexibility & control for the parent fragment as to when popping the stack or when the back action should be ignored by it, I rather use such implementation:

Defining a "ParentFragment" interface:

```
interface ParentFragment {
/**
 * Fragments that host child fragments and want to control their BackStack behaviour when the back button is pressed should implement this
 *
 * @return true if back press was handled, false otherwise
 */
fun onBackPressed(): Boolean
```

}

Overriding the "onBackPressed" in the parent activity (or in the BaseActivity):

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    for (frag in fm.fragments) {
        if (frag.isVisible && frag is ParentFragment && frag.onBackPressed()) {
            return
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

And then allow the parent fragment to handle as it wishes, for example:

```
override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    val childFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SomeChildFragment::class.java.simpleName)
    if (childFragment != null && childFragment.isVisible) {
        // Only for that case, pop the BackStack (perhaps when other child fragments are visible don't)
        childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This allows to avoid thinking that there is some legitimate child fragment to remove when using a view pager for example (and back stack entry count > 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I have an activity with a child fragment. That child fragment can then recursively create more versions of itself onto its childFragmentManager. So here is my code for my activity's onBackPressed function.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    // Get the child fragment manager of the displayed fragment
    var childFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.fragments.first().childFragmentManager

    // If there are nested fragments, handle those first
    if (childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        // If there are more nested fragments, go deeper into those
        var nestedChildFragmentManager = childFragmentManager.fragments.first().childFragmentManager
        while (nestedChildFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            childFragmentManager = nestedChildFragmentManager
            nestedChildFragmentManager = childFragmentManager.fragments.first().childFragmentManager
        }

        // Dismiss the innermost nested fragment
        childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    } else if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        // If there are no nested fragments, dismiss the original fragment
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    } else {
        // Otherwise, handle the back press as normal
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recently faced the issue it can be solved simply by adding this code to your child fragment holder Fragment

```
private val backCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
         childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
         isEnabled=childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount>1
    }
}
```

and add this code in oncreate

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(backCallback)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `DialogFragment` which in turn has nested fragments, the 'workaround' is a bit different. Instead of setting an `onKeyListener` to the `rootView`, you'll need to do that with the `Dialog`. Also you will be setting up a `DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` and not the `View` one. Of course, remember `addToBackStack`!

> Btw, having 1 fragment on the backstack for delegating the call back to the activity is my personal use case. Typical scenarios might be for the count to be 0.

Here's what you gotta do within the onCreateDialog

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    FragmentManager cfm = getChildFragmentManager();
                    if(cfm.getBackStackEntryCount()>1){
                        cfm.popBackStack();
                        return true;
                    }   
                }   
                return false;
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: Not really understandable or not complete. DialogFragment or it's superclass Fragment don't have setOnKeyListener.

Comment: @Ixx You have to set the listener on `Dialog` (not `DialogFragment`) and the listener you use is `DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` - the code is working and complete (and in use). Why don't you provide your situation and perhaps I can help.

Answer (score -1):

for ChildFragments this works..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

 if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            doExit(); //super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```