# Android: how to handle onBackPressed Nested fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm in an activity with the following structure

```
 Activity
   ContainerFragment with a view pager
       fragment 1 within viewPager
           View 1 inside fragment 1
           View 2 inside fragment 1
```

When the `activity` loads `fragment1.view1` is shown, if some user interaction happens `View 1 close and View 2 Open` (think of it as 2 cards, one gets hidden another gets shown).  From `View 1` on `back press` user should back to `View 1` .  This became more of a headache than I thought it would be.  The best I can come up with is to `override activity.onBackPressed()`, check if `containerFragment` is currently not `null` and call `containerFragment.onBackPressed()` (custom method), which then checks if `fragment1` is not `null` and calls `fragment1.onBackPressed()` which then checks if `view 2` is showing and if yes ,  then close  `View 2`  and show `view 1`.    Is there any simpler way in `android` to solve a problem like this?  I don't have control over restructuring this part of the app.

Summary: I have a `fragment` inside another `fragment` which contains 2 `views`, I want to on `backpressed` go from `view 2` to `view 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement something called `FragmentViewController`which would be responsible for display proper view in your Fragment. It's really simple, for example

```
class FragmentViewController{
      private boolean firstView = true;

      public boolean isFirstView() { return firstView }
      public void setFirstView() { firstView = true; }       
      public void setSecondView() { firstView = false; }
}
```

Show view in your Fragment **based on state** of `FragmentViewController`. After each change of state refresh Fragment to show proper view.

When view2 will be show, call `setSecondView()`.
Override `onBackPressed` in your Activity, and manage the state of `FragmentViewController` to handle back button pressed eg.: when view2 is showing call `setFirstView` to restore first view in Fragment.

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple and elegant solution. Problem solved.