# go back button between "grand child" fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that is holding 5 fragments.
One of those fragments is holding 5 more fragments.
if i add to the fragmentManager a .addToBackStack(null).
the back button returns to the last fragment from the activity and not to the last fragment from the "father" fragment (that is holding 5 more fragments).

Any help please..

EDIT:

```
ACTIVITY:

fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
            replace(mainContent.getId(), currentFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();


FRAGMENT:

fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
            replace(mainContent.getId(), currentFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Comment: Make sure all your `FragmentTransactions` are from the same FragmentManager. You're probably using two different fragment managers at the moment.

Comment: I am i have a activity.getFragmentManager.
and is the fragment i am using getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: i switched to the same fragment manager and then i get at the fragments Childs a null when i call getParentFragment

Comment: So you're using two Fragment Managers. What's the code you're calling on your 'back' inside the Fragment with child fragments? Also do you mean the physical back button?

Comment: i don't have any code in the "back" i just added to the transaction addToBackStack(null). and yes i mean the physical button

Comment: Share the code for your activity and fragment, at least the parts where you're creating fragment transactions and committing.

Comment: I think what you're facing is a bug in Android SDK. See my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the bug mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40323

You can workaround it by handling the 'back' manually. Refer to this thread for a lot of workarounds: [Android 4.2: back stack behaviour with nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418436/android-4-2-back-stack-behaviour-with-nested-fragments)

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue might be with "the fragmentManager" here. There is more than one `FragmentManager`.

There is the `FragmentManager` for the `Activity`  – [`Activity.getFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager%28%29).

And there is the `FragmentManager` for child `Fragment`s within a `Fragment` – [`Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) or [`Fragment.getFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()).

Let's say you have an `activity`, a `parentFragment` and a `childFragment`. So, instead of `activity.getFragmentManager()`, I think in your case, you might want either `childFragment.getFragmentManager()` or `parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager()`.

Note that if you are using the Support package, the names may be different.

Comment: I am using two fragmentManagers, but i need them.