# Nested fragment and back stack

Tags: android, back-stack, android-nested-fragment

I have a fragment in which there is a nested fragment which I add in this way:

```
            if (home == null) {
                home = new MyFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.addToBackStack(MyFragment.class.getName());
                transaction.add(R.id.child_fragment, home).commit();
            }
```

When I enter another fragment and go back the child fragment from above is not there. I checked and the instance is different from null.

**UPDATE**: I changed the code as suggested by Ashwin S Ashok but it's still not working.

Comment: try using add not replace.

Comment: Assuming the code above is in the parent fragment, does it work if you change `getFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: add/replace give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try using these methods:

// Use this if you don't want to retain the fragment.

```
protected void replaceFragmentStack(int container, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

// Use this if you want to add the fragments in a stack.

```
protected void addFragmentStack(int container, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.add(container, fragment, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but it's not working again. My other fragments work properly but not with the nested fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `getChildFragmentManager()` when making transactions inside a fragment. And its a bug i guess.
You can check out this thread it will help you alot [Android 4.2: back stack behaviour with nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418436/android-4-2-back-stack-behaviour-with-nested-fragments)

Also you need to go through The Curious Techizen's [blog](http://curioustechizen.blogspot.com/2014/02/nested-fragment-and-backstack-part-2.html)

Here is the link for the github [project](https://github.com/curioustechizen/blog-nested-fragments-backstack) sample for same mechanism

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. But I really would like to do it without the support library because I should make a lot of changes to the fragments.