# How to manage Backstack with child fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment, child-fragment

I am having issues with nested/child fragments. My use case is: I have Frag A as parent fragment and `FragChild1`, `FragChild2`, `FragChild3` as child fragments to be displayed inside `Frag A`. Now on back press from FragChild3 it should work like :

> FragChild3 -> FragChild2 -> FragChild1 -> FragA(ParentFrag).

The code I used to add child fragments are-

```
for ChildFrag1-

Fragment mChildFragment1 = new ChildFragment1();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_view, mChildFragment1);
        transaction.addToBackStack("FragChild1");
        transaction.commit();
        
for ChildFrag2-

Fragment mChildFragment2 = new ChildFragment2();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_view, mChildFragment2);
        transaction.addToBackStack("FragChild2");
        transaction.commit();
```

I have searched through StackOverflow for relevant answers but haven't yet found any proper answer/way of managing backstack for child fragments.

Comment: Is fragment 3 a child of fragment 2 and fragment 2 a child of fragment 1?

Comment: How are you displaying 1,2 and 3? Are you using a view pager?

Comment: No i am not using viewpager. Though i want the behaviour of child1,2,3 as viewpager only. And child1,2,3 are independent of each other . All 3 have parent as frag A and the child frags are placed in the same container

Comment: I want a viewpager behaviour with the child frags but i am using getChildFragmentMaager()

Comment: You actually need to override onBackPressed() event in your activity that hosts all these fragments and have to check manually which fragment is on top of the stack each time the back button is pressed.

Comment: Also 1,2 and 3 won't be independent exactly. They won't have parent-child relationship. However, there must be an order of visibility as per your requirement. If you want to go back as 3,2,1 then you also have to come forward as 1,2,3.

Comment: Right the order of visibility is 1,2,3 and their parent is not an activity but a fragment. I tried overriding backPressed which didn't work. That is my question exactly how to achieve this

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
        if (frag.isVisible()) {
            FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
            if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                childFm.popBackStack();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

Comment: I used the above code for popping child fragments

Comment: Why not let the `ViewPager` deal with this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: okay so the code that you are using to pop the fragments will actually start working if you add() fragments instead of replacing them.

Comment: Let the fragments overlap just manage the transition manually.

Comment: check out the code available in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418436/android-4-2-back-stack-behaviour-with-nested-fragments) post as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 4.2: back stack behaviour with nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418436/android-4-2-back-stack-behaviour-with-nested-fragments)

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems good. Just override `onbackpressed` method in activity that contains parent fragment and put given code in it.

```
if (parentfragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
    parentfragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: We can use the result of `parentfragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` for `if()`

Answer (score 1):

Now this behavior can be implemented with [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher) **without overriding `onBackPressed` in an Activity**.

In your parent fragment (where your fragment container is located) add this code in `onAttach` method:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val backCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Remove all fragments from the childFragmentManager,
            // but exclude the first added child fragment.
            // This child fragment will be deleted with its parent.
            if (childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1) {
                childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
                return
            }
            // Delete parent fragment
            parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backCallback)
}
```

Than add fragments in your container like this:

```
childFragmentManager.commit {
    replace(R.id.fragmentContainerRoot, fragment)
    addToBackStack(null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the tag into the replace method. TAG can as simple as the fragments name (String). Change your code like this:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container_view, mChildFragment1, "FragChild1");
transaction.addToBackStack("FragChild1");
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: Did you try add() instead of replace(). Because replace clears everything and adds your new fragment. And you need to override onbackpressed() if you use replace() along with addtoBackStack().

Comment: If I add instead of replace then the child fragments are overlapping .I am placing the child frags in the single container of parent

Comment: How to achieve the behaviour of popping each child fragment overriding onbackpressed ?

Comment: I would suggest, put all your logic in activity which means opening of the fragments should be in the activity, you shouldn't open Fragment B from Fragment A, instead tell activity that Fragment B should be opened (using interface). Now override the onbackpressed of activity NOT fragment's

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Fragment fragment= new ChildFragment1();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentView, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```