# Return result from fragment just as startActivityForResult in case Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, child-fragment

I have an activity in which I am adding fragments.There is a Fragment(WhenFragment) on which I add another fragment (DateSelectionFragment) to get the date and when I back press I need that date and want to set in a text view.I used OnFragmentInteractionListener for this which returns result in WhenFragment correctly.But I am not able to access Textview in that OnFragmentInteractionListener implementation to set date to it.

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Bundle bundle) {
   mBinding.textView.setText(bundle.getString("result"),"");
}
```

To get back to WhenFragment I am using

```
 getActivity().onBackPressed();
 mListener.onFragmentInteraction(bundle);
```

It is giving nullPointerException. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how are u adding the dateSelectionfragment ?

Comment: Just kill your `onFragmentInteraction` callback and restructure your code. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the back function as follows:-

```
 mListener.onFragmentInteraction(bundle);    
 getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Or

if your are you are adding the second fragment using `getChildFragmentManager()` then , first the fragment stack has to be managed, instead of the activity stack .something like:-

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

// If the fragment exists and has some back-stack entry
if (mActivityDirectFragment != null && mActivityDirectFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
    // Get the fragment fragment manager - and pop the backstack
    mActivityDirectFragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
// Else, nothing in the direct fragment back stack
else{
    // Let super handle the back press
    super.onBackPressed();          
}
}
```

Some helpfull links:-

[back stack behaviour with nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418436/android-4-2-back-stack-behaviour-with-nested-fragments)

[Sending data from nested fragments to parent fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142956/sending-data-from-nested-fragments-to-parent-fragment)

Answer (score -1):

You can store the value in sharedPreferences and then fetch it later from elsewhere.